# Moved from Michigan to Florida

Tags: united-states, rental-property

When I moved to Florida from Michigan the only thing I had to go by were the pictures in the ads and on their website.  When I got to Florida I found out the apartment complex they posted so many really nice picture of didn't look anything like the pictures at all.  It was horrible !  They so badly misrepresented this complex I didn't want to live there.  I thought my apartment would look like the pictures they showed, but it was nothing at all like they were showing.  Would this be considered fraud ?  They  misrepresented these apartments very badly.

Comment: You need more information on how different it was.

Comment: I know what's being shown on their website, but I also have plenty of pictures of what I saw when I got here.

Comment: I get that, but I mean you could be saying this looks different as in you don't like the decor or whatever or you could be saying they promised you three beadrooms and you got one. There is a huge difference in all the things that cold be what it being different than the pictures could mean.

Comment: The buildings looked like the pictures online, just very run down, trash everywhere, the other people in the apartments blinds were all mangled and a mess.  The online pictures didn't have a slummy look to them but in reality it looks just like a ghetto neighborhood would look like.  Very disgusting !

Comment: To constitute fraud, a misrepresentation or omission must also relate to an 'existing fact', not a promise to do something in the future, unless the person who made the promise did so without any present intent to perform it or with a positive intent not to perform it. Promises to do something in the future or a mere expression of opinion cannot be the basis of a claim of fraud unless the person stating the opinion has exclusive or superior knowledge of existing facts which are inconsistent with such opinion.

Comment: The false statement or omission must be material, meaning that it was significant to the decision to be made.

Sometimes, it must be shown that the plaintiff's reliance was justifiable, and that upon reasonable inquiry would not have discovered the truth of the matter. For injury or damage to be the result of fraud, it must be shown that, except for the fraud, the injury or damage would not have occurred.

Comment: To constitute fraud the misrepresentation or omission must be made knowingly and intentionally, not as a result of mistake or accident, or in negligent disregard of its truth or falsity. Also, the plaintiff must prove that the defendant intended for the plaintiff to rely upon the misrepresentation and/or omission; that the plaintiff did in fact rely upon the misrepresentation and/or omission; and that the plaintiff suffered injury or damage as a result of the fraud. Damages may include punitive damages as a punishment or public example due to the malicious nature of the fraud.

Comment: There are many state and federal laws to regulate fraud in numerous areas. Some of the areas most heavily litigated include consumer fraud, corporate fraud, and insurance fraud.

Comment: I copy & pasted what I found as the Legal Description of "FRAUD."  I truly believe this is exactly what they did.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Usually fraud in respect to the condition of real estate excludes anything that could be discerned with a quick visual inspection of the premises and the usual rule is buyer beware.

But, perhaps if the pictures were of a totally different complex, rather than merely selectively taken so as too make pictures of the actual complex seem better than they usually are. You could complain and try to get them to voluntarily let you out, but it is fairly unlikely that they would agree and litigating the issue would be nightmare and not very likely to succeed.

Comment: It's without a doubt it's the same apartment complex.  The pictures they show on line are nowhere close to what these apartments really look like.  I'm aware of the phrase "Buyer Beware" but I'm just renting, not buying.  Major False Advertising is what they are guilty of.  They shouldn't be allowed to get away with that.  They drew me in with the nice pictures, then slapped me in the face with reality when I got here.  That's just plain wrong !

Comment: @LindaDittenber We're not in the "the law should be like this" business. We're a "here's reality as it is" gig.

Comment: How sad.  They know that when you're coming from out of state the pictures they show you are all you have to go by.  I was taken advantage of and scammed for no other reason than they knew they could get away with it.

Comment: See my further comments above.  Thanks !